# IGenericRepository<T> : where T : classnot working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my class in mvc4:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;

namespace xxx.Areas.admin.Models
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> : where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> AsQueryable();

        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>>  predicate);
        T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T GetById(int id);

        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Attach(T entity);
    }
}
```

but there're some errors:

> - The type or namespace name 'where' could not be found (are you    missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> - The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue? If it did, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) from the where generic constraint you have to do it this way:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

You must not have the : between the IGenericRepository< T> and the where.